# Forcing application to go to selected window on startup

Tags: macos, applescript, display

I run a multi-monitor set-up on a single "Desktop". All of my applications when opened run on the primary monitor, which is the smaller monitor. I would like to have some (e.g. browser, mail client) open on my secondary, with others (e.g. IRC, terminal, etc) on my primary.

I'm unsure if there's a method to do this natively or if this requires coding, however I'm happy with either solution.

Comment: Launch, drag to 2nd screen, relaunch. Not working?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The machine is a macbook pro, so sometimes I have it plugged into a screen (at work), other times it's just open on its own (at home). Outlook for Mac 2016 always opens in the macbook, whilst other processes seem to flick between them.

Comment: Ah, as soon as you reduce the machine to one screen, it will pull all windows back inside that screen, so you don't lose them. Intended behaviour. SavedState might send a window to the second screen if it was there last time the app was launched, but not all apps save state - that may be why you're seeing the discrepancy. [MS does its own thing always, even with 2 permanent screens, RDC will open on the 2nd screen, but every connection I ever open opens on screen 1]